# How can I deploy middleman to a VPS?

Tags: ruby, deployment, web-deployment, middleman

I have a middleman project that I want to deploy it to a **VPS**. the documentation of middleman(build/deploy) is very poor and the gem that name it there (middleman-deploy) is not working.

My question is **how can I deploy the project in my own hand without a gem**?
Is the build folder enough for deployment? I mean, can I just copy that folder to production server or something else?
Thank you.

Comment: If you need mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Comment: Just copy and paste the `build` directory content into any normal webhosting. It should just work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right

Simply copy the `/build` and push it to your VPS.

If you want to automate this task have a look at `after_build` method

https://middlemanapp.com/advanced/custom-extensions#after_build

```
  'bundle exec middleman build',
  'echo "== Build the project =="',
  'cd build/',
  'git add -A',
  'git commit -m build',
  'echo "== Pushing changes =="',
  'git push origin master',
```